# search using regex in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, regex, spring, jpql

I am trying to do a simple search function by multiple words, like this in SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM faqs WHERE title REGEXP 'préférée|Changer|endommagé' or question REGEXP 'préférée|Changer|endommagé'
```

but when I tried to implement this in `@Query` in my JpaRepository like this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT f FROM Faq f WHERE f.title REGEXP :term" )
Page<Faq> searchByRegExp(@Param("term") String term,Pageable pageable);
```

But it seems that `REGEXP` isnt supported because of this error:

```
<expression>, <operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected, got 'REGEXP'
```

Note: I tried adding `nativeQuery = true` - same issue:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM faqs WHERE title REGEXP :term ", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<Faq> searchByRegExp(@Param("term") String term,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: The same error when `nativeQuery = true`?

Comment: Yes I updated the post

Comment: Does it work without `Pageable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately jpql does not support regular expressions. You would have to use `like` and write all the possibilities. But in your case you can simply use `in`:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT f FROM Faq f WHERE f.title in (:terms)" )
Page<Faq> searchByRegExp(@Param("terms") List<String> terms, Pageable pageable);
```

And as the first parameter pass the possibilities: `List.of("préférée", "Changer", "endommagé")`. For more complex regular expressions this list would grow considerably, but in this case only 3 values are possible.

The other way is using `nativeQuery` and sql:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT f.* FROM faqs f WHERE (f.title REGEXP :term)", nativeQuery = true)
Page<Faq> searchByRegExp(@Param("term") String term,Pageable pageable);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use regexp? Because this is just an example the number of the possibilities is unknown. Or searching function done by another way that I don't know ?

Comment: @S4L4H if your database allows it, then with `nativeQuery` should work. What's the error?

Comment: its says <expression>, <operator>, GROUP, HAVING or ORDER expected, got 'REGEXP'

Comment: Yes it returns what I am looking for

Comment: @S4L4H I've changed it a bit, can you try it now?

Comment: It works, apparently my IDE underlines 'REGEXP' but the application still runs. Thanks dude it works now with nativeQuery

Comment: @S4L4H the problem was probably the lack of parentheses - hibernate might have added something that broke the syntax. Consider upvoting ;>

Comment: Jpql neither support NOACCENTS, COLLATE or regexp. It's just a constraint, not a really useful tool.